# Why aren't related questions shown on the mobile interface?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, related-questions

I've recently joined the Stack Exchange community, and like reading questions in my free time, or when I'm on the bus, via the mobile webpage. The main site has a right bar with Linked and Related questions, which are usually interesting.

Why aren't these questions shown on the mobile interface too? Maybe at the bottom (you can't have columns in mobile, can you?), but it would be very nice to have them and continue exploring the questions withoutt having to switch to the full site.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're on Android or iOS7+, the best way to explore questions from the network is to install our official mobile app.

I don't really see us adding lists of questions to the mobile web views at this point since they'd come off largely too cluttered, and the views aren't designed to fully mimic the desktop version in the first place.

Comment: I'm on Windows Phone.

Comment: Maybe the main question could have a “related questions” link, and then the list opens in a new page. No clutter.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez I'm sorry to hear that. :) (Sorry, couldn't help myself.) Hmm. Yeah, a link is a possibility.